# keeping multiple responsive DIV's the same height inside a containing DIV using only css

Tags: html, css

The content area under the NAV has a DIV (class="threeSpread) which contains three DIVs (ID="top", "middle", and "bottom") that are styled the same.  Each has an image which are sized the same but have a differnt amount of H2 and P text.

The problem is that the height of the DIVs do not stay the same.  They seem to adjust differently becuase the amount of text inside is differnt for each box.
When the browser screen is adjusted sometimes the three DIVs render at the same height, but it is not consistant.

I thought that the fix would be to style the DIV's with the height property at 100%, but that did not have any effect.....

[Here is an image of the page](http://uploadpie.com/CH5hf)

and the HTML and CSS below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="menu">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



        <div class="threeSpread">
        <div id="top">
        <img src="imagesForNew/new1.jpg">
        <h2>CHININESE INVESTORS COME TO DETROIT</h2>
        <p>"the Shanghai-based developer Dongdu International (DDI) made its first move. In an online auction, it snapped up three iconic downtown properties, all built during the citys early 20th-century"</p>
         <a href="http://www.theguardian.com/cities/2014/jul/22/does-multimillion-dollar-chinese-investment-signal-detroits-rebirth">theguardian.com</a>
        </div>

        <div id="middle">
        <img src="imagesForNew/new2.gif">
        <h2>Donald Trump sees Detroit as a good investment</h2>
        <p>"What Dan Gilbert did is fantastic. When he sees something like that, it's a good sign"

    Trump said he also sees Detroit as a potential investment opportunity.

    "A lot of times when I go to a place."</p>
         <a href="http://www.crainsdetroit.com/article/20130501/BLOG003/130509990/donald-trump-sees-detroit-as-a-good-investment">crainsdetroit.com</a>
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
        <img src="imagesForNew/new3.gif">
        <h2>Warren Buffett calls Detroit land of 'Huge Potential'</h2>
        <p>Chairman and found of Rock Ventures and Quicken Loans Dan Gilbert, not pictured, interviews Berkshire Hathaway Chairman Warren Buffett, during an event at Detroit Homecoming</p>
         <a href="http://www.mlive.com/business/detroit/index.ssf/2014/09/billionaire_banter_dan_gilbert.html">Mlive.com</a>
        </div>

        </div>








    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </body>
    </html>


/****************************
*****************************
NEWS Side fluid layout
*****************************
****************************/
div.threeSpread {
    width: 99%;


clear: both;

border: solid black 1px;


}

div#top, div#middle, div#bottom  {
    max-width: 20%;
    border: solid green 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5%;
    height: 100%;
}



@media (max-width: 900px) {

    div#top, div#middle, div#bottom  {

    display: block;
    border: solid red 1px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;


}

/** Adjusts the text inside the three boxes
 to move more to the center in the vertical stack view **/
div#top h2, div#middle h2, div#bottom h2 {
    margin: 10% 0 auto;
        height: 100%;
}

div#top img, div#bottom img {
    float: right;
}

div#middle img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use flexbox.
for example

```
div.threeSpread {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You have the full example here http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/LNWWaR with the prefixes, as well I remove the code that I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach :

```
.threeSpread {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 30px 0;
}

#top, #middle, #bottom {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
   .threeSpread {
     border-spacing: 0;
    }
}
```

Here's a working example - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb57uh2f/)

You could do this using `display: flex`, however, this isn't supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align: top;
```

This will align all your divs to the top instead to the bottom. Set this on the div top, middle and bottom.
`min-height`

```css
min-height: 40em
```

If you would like to keep all heights the same as well, you can set min-height as well to be the largest possible height that you will have/allow.

[Example DEMO](http://codepen.io/lili2311/pen/JXWNeO)